# What are the pros and cons of scheduling celery beat periodic tasks at 0.1 seconds?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, celery, celerybeat

My application requires to run periodic tasks(task to check a flag) every second. But sometimes it appears the task is not executed in the expected period of 1 second. So I have changed it to execute at period 0.1 seconds. i.e, the task checks the flag 10 times every second.

```
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'task-number-one': {
        'task': 'app.tasks.periodic_runner',
        'schedule': 0.1,
        'args': [],
        'relative': True
    },
    'task-number-two': {
        'task': 'app.tasks.periodic_assigner',
        'schedule': 0.1,
        'args': [],
        'relative': True
    }
}
```

What are the pros and cons?
This task hits the database each time it is executed.

I have five such tasks.

Does it destroy my server in any way in the long run?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what else is going on.  Deciding on whether your application can scale to support this many tasks requires some back-of-the-envelope calculations.  By running these at 100ms intervals, we are executing

10 tasks per second * 60 seconds / minute * 60 minutes / hour = 36,000 tasks per hour.  That means every hour we are making 36,000 i/o operations to the broker, 72,000 i/o operations to the results backend, and n * 36,000 calls to the database where n is the number of database calls per task.    With everything else that you have going on, and with the resources that you have deployed in your architecture, do any of these numbers pose a problem?

For example, let's say that your database is a mongodb database, and your task is requesting information on an unindexed field.  Then, yes, this many requests will probably lock up mongodb.  But if you're using redis and mysql in AWS with 8GB instances backing each, you should be able to handle all of that without breaking a sweat.

Comment: I am using redis and mysql on a ubuntu server of digitalocean. Somewhere I feel after reducing the period to 100ms, the web appears to be loading too slow.